# Postman monitor not combining two arrays correctly. Runner works fine

Tags: postman, javascript-objects

Describe the Issue

I am trying to create an object that consists of two arrays; one that is a member and the other for its values. Lets just assume they are stocks and their prices for simplicity.

Steps to Reproduce

Create two arrays:

1. Stock Tickers (TSLA, AAPL, etc) = rollover_Watchlist
2. Stock prices (150, 200, etc) = rollover_Prices
   I used the following code to create the object from these two arrays:

   var result = {};
   rollover_Watchlist.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = rollover_Prices[i]);
   console.log(result);

The above code works in the runner but not in the monitor for some reason.

Screenshots or Videos

The result works in the collection runner as expected but when I use the monitor I am getting incorrect results as follows:

Runner:
[image]

Monitor:
[image]

Environment Information

Platform Type: Postman Monitor
Postman Version: Postman v8.3.0
Operating System: Windows 10
Additional Context

I tried Stringify when setting the variable arrays and then parsing them when I 'get ' them but that did not fix it.

Really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. When I was pulling the array the monitor was reading it as a string as opposed to an array of numbers:

https://community.postman.com/t/split-is-suddenly-not-recognised-as-a-function/1117/10